# How to push to a specific branch of a specific remote?

Tags: git

I'm trying to follow the [Aptible Django Quickstart Tutorial](https://www.aptible.com/documentation/enclave/tutorials/quickstart-guides/python/django.html) for project which has an existing git repository. After completing the step

```
git remote add aptible "$GIT_REMOTE"
```

where `$GIT_REMOTE` is the git remote created by the `aptible apps:create` command with the Aptible CLI, I now have two remote repositories:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro:lucy-web kurtpeek$ git remote -v
aptible git@beta.aptible.com:lucy/web.git (fetch)
aptible git@beta.aptible.com:lucy/web.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/startwithlucy/lucy.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/startwithlucy/lucy.git (push)
```

Before doing that, I created a new branch which is also called `aptible` and checked it out (using `git checkout -b aptible`). My `git status` shows I'm currently on this branch:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro:lucy-web kurtpeek$ git status
On branch aptible
```

What I would now like to do is push the contents of the `aptible` branch on the `origin` remote to the `master` branch of the `aptible` remote. How can I do this? Would the appropriate command be

```
git push aptible:master origin:aptible
```

?

Comment: Which branch do you base to create `aptible` branch?

Comment: If the `origin` has a branch called `aptible`, you can use `git checkout origin/aptible` to check it out and a local branch called `aptible` will be created automatically. Then you can use `git push aptible master:master` to push your local branch to the remote server `aptible`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To push a branch to different remote,

Then push the git content to remote (aptible)

```
git push aptible HEAD:master
```

**UPDATE:** Apparently, you don't need to checkout branch before you push them. However, if you want to view/fix the branch, you can checkout using `git checkout aptible`

Comment: No need to do `checkout`. You can push non-current branch: `git push aptible aptible:master`.

Comment: If I try `git push aptible aptible:master`, I get an error from Aptible's platform: `remote: ERROR -- : No Dockerfile found. Aborting!`. This happens even after I do `git add .` followed by `git commit` to add the entire contents of the  `aptible` branch. Should this command not push all contents of the `aptible` branch to the `master` branch on the `aptible` remote?

Comment: Regarding my last comment, I've learned that this was because Aptible expects the `Dockerfile` to be in the root directory of the repository (which it wasn't), and not because it wasn't getting pushed. After moving the `Dockerfile` up a directory (and modifying it accordingly), `git push aptible aptible:master` worked just fine.